# How can I turn this 'while' loop into a 'for' loop?

Tags: python

I'm working through LPTHW, on exercise 33, and on the very last study drill, they ask to change the code I have to a 'for' loops, rather than the 'while' loop I've written. Here's the code I've come up with:

```
numbers = []

def loop(i, x, new_num):
    while i < x:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + new_num
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num

loop(0, 10, 6)
```

Now the study drill instructs me to, "Now, write it to use for- loops and range instead. Do you need the incrementor in the
middle anymore? What happens if you do not get rid of it?"

This is how far I've managed to get, but I've got no idea if I'm going in the right direction. Basically just shooting in the dark:

```
numbers = []
new_numbers = [0]
def loop2():
    for i in new_numbers: 
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)
```

I don't know where to insert a 'range' function either. If I managed to turn this into a 'for' loop that did exactly what this 'while' loop code does, what would it look like?

Comment: You need to try something using `for i in range(...`

Comment: Take a look at what [`range` function](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) does.

Comment: `for item in range(i, x, new_num)`

Comment: @DavidGreydanus: Yes. I am not sure if OP knows what purpose is `range` function and how it can be used with `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your working example with the while loop, you assign `i = i + new_num` during each loop, so you iterate `i` by `new_num`. This can be easily replicated with `range`.

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) takes up to 3 arguments: `(starting_point, upper_bound, num_to_iterate_by)`

In your code, `i` is the starting point, `x` is the upper bound, and `new_num` is the number you iterate by each loop.

**Note:** The third argument in a for loop is optional. Python will use 1 as the default iterator if none is specified.

**Changes from your code:**

1. Replaced`while i < x:` with `for i in range(i, x, new_num):` at line 4
2. Removed `i = i + new_num` at line 8

-

```
numbers = []

def loop(i, x, new_num):
    for i in range(i, x, new_num):
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num

loop(0, 10, 6)
```

**Output:**

```
At the top i is 0
Numbers now:  [0]
At the bottom i is 0
At the top i is 6
Numbers now:  [0, 6]
At the bottom i is 6
The numbers: 
0
6
```

Comment: `for i in range(i, ..` is confusing.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. I have a question for you though. When building this script, how did you go about creating it? Do you think about making it from the inside out (ie. making the loops, and then building the function around it?). Or do you create the function first, and then the loops? I'm just learning programming, and trying to think about what is the best approach to writing code.

Comment: I go about solving problems top down. I first think about the functionality I want, and then the features I can use to implement those ideas. I start by making a function, and then fill it in with code.

Comment: @shahkalpesh That was a mistake. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score -1):

By using for in range => `for i in range(x,y)`

```
numbers = []

def loop(i, x, new_num):
    for i in range(i, x):
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + new_num
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


  print "The numbers: "

  for num in numbers:
    print num

loop(0, 10, 6)
```